# Homeomorphic mapping

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

The so-called Homeomorphic mapping theorem is that

> If $H(z):\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is a continuous map and satisfies the
>   following conditions:
>
> (i) $H(z)$ is injective on $\mathbb{R}^n$,
>
> (ii) $\lim_{\|z\|\to\infty}\|H(z)\|=\infty$,
>
> then $H(z)$ is a homeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}^n$ onto itself.

How to prove the theorem? Please give the proof or recommend a book about the theorem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never heard that name before, but I think the result is easy enough to prove.

The key result for this proof is

> [**Invariance of domain**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain): if $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ is continuous and injective, then $f$ is open and is a homeomorphism from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $im(f)$.

*(Actually IoD says more than this, but that's what I'll use here. Note that the statement "$f$ is a homeomorphism to its image" already follows from $f$ being an open map.)*

So surjectivity is all that's left to prove. Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ is continuous, injective, and *not* surjective. Let $x$ be a boundary point of $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus im(f)$; since the latter set is closed ($f$ being open), $x\not\in im(f)$.

Consider a sequence $y_i\rightarrow x$ with $y_i\in im(f)$ (such a sequence exists since $x$ is on the boundary of $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus im(f)$). Let $a_i=f^{-1}(y_i)$.

Now, think about the $a_i$s. Could they have bounded norm in $\mathbb{R}^n$? Well, then they'd all lie in some finite-radius closed ball, which is compact, so we would have a convergent subsequence $b_i\rightarrow b$. But the continuity of $f$ would then require $f(b)=x$, a contradiction.

So the $a_i$s don't have bounded norm. Then we can extract a subsequence $c_i$ whose norm tends to infinity. Now apply the condition on what $f$ does to norms . . .

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But I have a question. Now a subsequence $c_i$ is found such that $\|c_i\|\to \infty$, Then $\|f(c_i)\|\to \infty$. I don't understand why $f$ is surjective.

Comment: @xiaofengChen Well, that's a contradiction - we know that $f(c_i)\rightarrow x$, so $\vert f(c_i)\vert$ does **not** go to $\infty$. (This is a proof by contradiction. We've assumed $f$ *wasn't* surjective, and derived something we know not to be true.)

Comment: Thanks very much for your detailed proof. I have understood now. if f is defined on $\mathbb{C}^n$, where $\mathbb{C}$ is complex domain, the result holds too. What spaces can be use for the definition domain of $f$ such that the same result holds. As @Aloizio Macedo said, the definition domain can be compact Hausdorff spaces.

Answer (score 0):

The conditions imply that the map extends continuously to the one-point compactification.

So we have $\widetilde{f}: S^n \to S^n$. This extension is clearly injective by definition. Suppose $\widetilde{f}$ is not surjective. Therefore, it misses a point. It would follow that you would be able to embed $S^n$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, which is absurd, by invariance of domain.

The extension being now bijective, continuous, and defined in compact Hausdorff spaces, you have a homeomorphism. Restrict to get back the original function.

Comment: Thanks very much. I don't understand completely. I will study more knowledge so that understand your proof.

Comment: It would seem that invariance of domain (which is not an easy result) can be avoided. Just do what Noah did in his proof to get subjectivity.

Comment: @zhw. I am not sure. He needs $f$ to be open for his argument, which follows from invariance of domain.